# I am getting error when running spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've the following error:

```
Dec 20, 2021 2:47:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [springmvc] in web application [/springmvc] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is not clear and needs more details in order to be understood fully, I would suggest adding the maven dependency: `jakarta.servlet-api`